# Return an array of data from PHP to jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, netbeans

Building a website for my kid's bday which will allow his grandparents to log on and click through 15gigs worth of pics/vids from every day of the last two years. Can't seem to capture any data from my PHP program in jQuery however. AND I keep receiving an error that reads: 
**"Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE (03:27:54:409 | error, network at public_html/pics/desi/desiPics.php"**. 
I thought the procedure was relatively simple. Am I overcomplicating it somehow?

From desiPics.php:

```
<?php
$dir= glob('pics/desi/{*.jpg,*jpeg,*png,*gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
echo json_encode($dir);
?>
```

From jQuery:

```
var desiPics = [];
  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'pics/desi/desiPics.php',
   cache: false,
   async: true,
   success: function(result){
       if(result){
           desiPics = eval(result);
           alert(desiPics.length);
       }else{
           alert('error');
       }
     }
 });
```

Comment: It looks like the path to desiPics.php is wrong in your ajax call.  If desiPics.php has to look down into pics/desi/ to find the files, it's probably not down in those folders.  Make sure you can get to the url without ajax first, you probably just need to change it to `url: 'desiPics.php'`, also you aren't passing variables so the POST might not be needed, depending on what else is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to parse the json that is returned into an object to use it in the method you are.

```
success: function(result){
   result = JSON.parse(result);
   if(result){
       desiPics = result;
       alert(desiPics.length);
   }else{
       alert('error');
   }
 }
```

Edit: I added the dataType "json" which will convert result to an object.

```
var desiPics = [];
  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'pics/desi/desiPics.php',
   cache: false,
   async: true,
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(result){
   if(result){
       desiPics = result;
       alert(desiPics.length);
   }else{
       alert('error');
   }
 }
});
```

Comment: jquery will parse it for you if set dataType or if header is set at server for `application/json`. Also no need for use of `eval()`

Comment: all suggestions noted. same result.

Comment: Try visiting pics/desi/desiPics.php directly to make sure there is a response from the page.  If there is nothing displayed there may be an issue with you php document response.

Comment: forgot to remove `JSON.parse()` which I believe, given your edit, is somewhat redundant. apologies for the delay and thanks.